# Kendo UI Grid . how use Different type off combo box at grid in each row?

Tags: user-interface, combobox, kendo-ui, grid

I want to make a grid and use a different combo box in each row. For example, in a row of combo box the name of the country is in the row below the combo box type of products and the same procedure

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a [Row Template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/rowtemplate) where you can display a record on multiple lines? It helps to show some code with what you have tried.

Comment: Do you want to repeat group of county,product compbox between each two rows in the kendo grid?